# Retrieving nested bookmars in a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, dictionary, collections, itext

I'm writing a program to retrieve the titles of nested bookmarks in a pdf file, using iTextSharp 5.5.10.

I wrote a recurring function that takes a `Dictionary<string, object>` object as input parameter and returns a `List<string>` object, but doesn't work.

```
public static List<string> bookmarksList(Dictionary<string, object> parent)
{
    List<string> PDFbookmarks = new List<string>();

    if (parent.ContainsKey("Kids"))
    {
        PDFbookmarks.Add(parent["Kids"].ToString());
        Dictionary<string, object> child = parent["Kids"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        bookmarksList(child);
    }

    return PDFbookmarks;
}
```

The `Dictionary<string, object>` object I got it from the `GetBookmark(PDFReader)` method.

Setting aside the fact that the `ToString()` method doesn't obviously give me the actual child's title, the problem is I get a `NullReferenceException` at the first recurring call: when I try to inizialize the child variable in the function, it gets a `null` pointer.

The associated value to the `Kids` key is an `IList<Dictionary<string, object>>` object itself, as shown in the debug windows:

`System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]]]`
*(though this should be a `List` object, not an `IList`, am I wrong?)*

so I don't get it why I got a `null` pointer instead...

Any hints?

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: Please post final solutions as an *answer*, not add part of the *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought downcasting would've worked, but it didn't. Changing the variable declaration made my day. I also rewrote the whole function and now it fully works as intended.

```
public static List<string> BookmarksList(Dictionary<string, object> parent, List<string> bookmarkList)
{
    if (parent.ContainsKey("Kids"))
    {
        IList<Dictionary<string,object>> child = parent["Kids"] as IList<Dictionary<string, object>>;

        foreach(Dictionary<string, object> tmpChild in child)
        {
            bookmarkList.Add(tmpChild["Title"].ToString());
            MyClass.BookmarksList(tmpChild, bookmarkList);
        }
    }
    return bookmarkList;
}
```